# Magento 2 how to add image field in product attribute dropdown?

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.3

how to add image field in product attribute dropdown?
Please check below 2 image

magento 1 
[image]

Magento 2
[image]

you can check in both image in Magento 1 image there are 3-4 fields extra like flag image, thumbnail, image.

how can we do the same in Magento 2?

I am only able to create yes-no fields in attribute under Storefront Properties tab.

Comment: try changing dropdown into swatches, But you have only opttion to upload a single image or Choose a color option..There is no option for adding multiple images

Comment: You can create attribute with "Image Media" type, but it can allow you to upload a single image and you can set it on PDP. check this image: https://nimb.ws/zo8ykS

Comment: @aravind I want to upload 3 images.
Is it possible?

Comment: @KKR how to add a column with dropdown?

Comment: @sumeetbajaj can you please explain where you want to add dropdown column and what you want to do with that dropdown ?

Comment: @KKR i want to add one more column when admin create new attribute(which is dropdown) and i need three values of dropdown.Please check screenshot iin my questions.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `Dropdown` type attribute select `Visual Swatch` it will allow to upload an image or choose a color for the Attribute value.

https://prnt.sc/oefvvc

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I want to add a column with dropdown

Comment: This makes sense! ;-)